# Microsoft Solver Foundation: Enterprise edition

Tags: ms-solver-foundation

Where can I download the enterprise edition of Microsoft Solver Foundation? I am able to get the express edition online, but it has a limit on the number of variables and constraints. I want to solve large LPs using the enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically it was available as a purchase from [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/).

However the software is now defunct(*) and I no longer see it on their site. You can see how it used to look [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110430231749/http://gurobi.com/html/msf.html).

You might try contacting them directly.

(*)*In May 2012 last year, the Solver Foundation team wrote:
The current 3.1 release of MSF will be the last release as a standalone install.  We are working hard on integrating Microsoft Solver Foundation into a larger analytics framework that will help users build both prescriptive and predictive analytics.  We look forward to releasing this new product for your use as soon as we are able to do so.  This new product will provide a migration path for current Solver Foundation users and partners.*

Comment: Thank you. So if I want to solve LPs of large sizes, what is a good software to use?

Comment: @user2464953 AMPL (http://www.ampl.com) is a popular algebraic modeling language that supports a large number of commercial LP (and other) solvers such as CPLEX, Gurobi, Xpress and open-source ones like CBC and IPOPT.

Answer (score 1):

if you have msdn subscription, then try standard edition first. also academic license is an option if eligible.